# Minecraft Bedrock edition remove added NBT tags

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying (using an external NBT editor) to add a tag onto a fireball in order to make a small but powerful bomb, but the game is removing this tag. I did everything as described on the wiki:

- Tag name: ExplosionPower
- Tag type: int
- Only for Fireball

The tag appears to be added correctly, but the game removes it! The same happens for the `EntityData` tag, which is needed to customize spawn eggs.

I can't find a list of NBT tags for Bedrock edition; all I've found for Bedrock edition is `CanDestroy`.

Here's a video which shows me adding the `ExplosionPower` tag with the NBT editor, and then the game removing it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5aqvojmectgayg4/SCR_20180224_174217.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Can you show us your current command?

Comment: Command? Click to link and watch video

Comment: No. Your question has to stand on its own, with maybe a pic. If you have to click a link to understand the question, you haven't finished writing your question.

Comment: Do not you understand? I already described it in great detail, but if you do not understand something, watch the video. What else do you need?

Comment: How about giving us the command you're trying. We don't need all the extra explanation. We need the command.

Comment: I do it NOT with the help of a command, but with the help of the PROGRAM. With the help of commands this can not be done. I ask why the game removes this tag. Other tags are added and edited normally. Be kind to watch the video, if it's not clear

Comment: If we have to watch the video to understand your question, *it's not a good question*. In  fact, that's generally a good reason to close it. So if you want help, how about you put in the effort to provide additional information?

Comment: In my opinion, I explained everything correctly, that you do not understand ??? What??? Just repeated a problem that is not in the team

Comment: I'm voting to close as you will not provide the information required to answer the question. I'm done trying to explain. Either provide it, or don't. I don't care anymore.

Comment: I glanced at your video, but I think it's unreasonable to make people watch an 8 minute long video. From what I saw, it seems like you're using a third-party application, in which case we can't really help much -- we're not experts on how to use specific, arbitrary tools that may have their own bugs. Though Frank may have been a little bit abrasive here, I have to agree that this question does not currently stand on its own.

Comment: Seems likely that the `ExplosionPower` tag just doesn't exist in Bedrock from what you're describing. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any good documentation on what tags exist/don't in Bedrock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bedrock has no direct ingame NBT access and as such there's no proper list for all data tags. Bedrock is pretty locked down. If you want to know what tags are used, your best bet is to look at vanilla entities/items/etc. with an external editor.